# I want to change the default target in windows explorer edit/copy to folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Very infuriating. Copying file or folder in Windows Explorer. Highlight file, go to Edit/ Copy to folder ... and you get a browser. There is however a pre selected "default target" or start position often in my case it would seem a seldom used folder and to get to where I wish to copy to there is much navigation needed. Nowhere can I discover how this folder came to be the default location and nowhere can I discover how to change it. Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have added a program to your computer that provides you with this `Edit>Copy to ...` option, as Windows 7 does not provide this option.

HOWEVER, to answer the question, the file browser remembers the place you browsed to last time, and presents that place to you when it pops up.

[image]

If this is a problem, remember that you have in the left sidebar a few options to make things easier, like libraries, desktop, etc, and your Favorites. You can customize Favorites and put whatever you like in there for easier use.

Comment: Thank you but this is not quite the full story. Windows Explorer in Windows 7 does have a menu system and under Edit we get Copy to folder ...  and  Move to folder ... When using either of these we get a small browser window where the default is not determined by the site last used but seems fixed. It is this I am trying to change

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution and assuming you want to copy files to the same locations, you can [customize the Windows 7/Vista "Send To" menu item](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/), which appears when you right-click on a file/folder.